# Set union and inclusion.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $A^\circ$ be the collection of interior points of A. I want to prove that
$$A^\circ\cup B^\circ\subset(A\cup B)^\circ.$$
I know how to prove this, but someone asked me about if the following way is correct or not. It goes,
$$A\cup B\supset A\quad\text{and}\quad
A\cup B\supset B$$
Thus
$$A^\circ\cup B^\circ\subset(A\cup B)^\circ.$$
Is it correct?
I know this holds for intersection, but not sure about union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with your proof. Since you mentioned that $A\subset A\cup B$ and 
 $B\subset A\cup B$, much better if you include that $A^\circ\subset(A\cup B)^\circ$ and $B^\circ\subset(A\cup B)^\circ$ so that
$$A^\circ\cup B^\circ\subset (A\cup B)^\circ.$$

---

Alternately, we have
$A^\circ\subset A\quad\text{and}\quad B^\circ\subset B$. Thus, we get
$$A^\circ\cup B^\circ\subset A\cup B.$$
This means that $A^\circ\cup B^\circ$ is an open subset of $A\cup B$. But $(A\cup B)^\circ$ is the largest open subset of $A\cup B$. Hence,
$$A^\circ\cup B^\circ\subset(A\cup B)^\circ\subset A\cup B.$$